# Prove that there is a unique point $(x_0,y_0)$ in $K\cap\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x,y > 0\}$ such that $x_0y_0\geqslant xy$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, real-numbers

Here is what I am trying to prove:
We are given a set $$P^{+} = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x,y > 0\}$$

and a convex, compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $K\cap P^{+} \neq \emptyset$. Prove that there is a unique point $(x_0,y_0)$ in $K\cap P^{+}$ such that $x_0y_0 \geqslant xy$ for all $x,y\in K\cap P^{+}$.

Here's how I've started:

Since $K\cap P^{+} \neq \emptyset$, there is at least one element in this set. There are two cases to consider. Firstly, since a one-point set is closed and bounded, it is necessarily compact by Heine-Borel. Then if we have $K\cap P^{+}= \{(a,b)\}$, where $a, b > 0$, setting $x_0 = a$ and $y_0 = b$ gives the equality $xy=x_0y_0$ for all $x,y\in K$. Now suppose that there is more than one element in $K\cap P^{+}$. The set is convex, so the resulting plot in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be that of a closed polygon. Clearly, there will be a point $(x_0, y_0)$ satisfying the desired inequality. Now to prove uniqueness, suppose $(x_1, y_1)$ is a point distinct from $(x_0, y_0)$ which satisfies the desired inequality. Let $x_2 = \lambda x_0 + (1-\lambda)x_1$ and $y_2 = \lambda y_0 + (1-\lambda)y_1$ where $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Then $x_2y_2 = \lambda^2x_0y_0 + \lambda(1-\lambda)x_0y_1 + \lambda(1-\lambda)x_1y_0 + (1-\lambda)^2x_1y_1 > xy$...

I'm not sure if this approach is correct, but if it is, then how would I complete it? Also, is there a more rigorous way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The function $xy,$ when restricted to $K \cap \bar P,$ has a maximum $x_0y_0.$ But $(x_0, y_0)$ cannot be in $\partial{P}$ because $xy = 0$ for every point $(x,y)$ in the frontier of $P.$

Comment: Is this problem related to one of Nash's results?

Comment: its more the proof of uniqueness that I'm after

Comment: I can't find a way to write it formally but the set of points $(s,t)$ such that $st=x_0y_0$ is a hyperbole, so it should cut the convex set in exactly one point.